# Transformar las columnas agrupadas en columnas solas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Tengo una groupedby dataframe y me gustaria prepararla para hacer una regression.

```
>>>ts = sales.groupby(['date_block_num','shop_id'])['item_cnt_day'].sum()
date_block_num  shop_id
0               0          5578.0
                1          2947.0
                2          1146.0
                3           767.0
                4          2114.0
                            ...  
33              1         1972.0
                2         1263.0
                3         2316.0
                4         1446.0
                5          790.0
```

Y me gustaria obtener:

```
shop_id         1    ...    33 
0          5578.0       1972.0
1          2947.0       1263.0
2          1146.0       2316.0
3           767.0       1446.0
4          2114.0        790.0
```

Para ser capaz de crear un nube de puntos como lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta hoy intenté:

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=ts.date_block_num, index= ts.shop_id, data=ts)
```

pero me devuelve:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-82ae77e8cda8> in <module>()
----> 1 pd.DataFrame(columns=ts.date_block_num, index= ts.shop_id, data=ts)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5137             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5138                 return self[name]
-> 5139             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5140 
   5141     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'date_block_num'
```

El data original esta como eso:

```
>>> sales
    date    date_block_num  shop_id item_id item_price  item_cnt_day
0   2013-01-02  0   59  22154   999.00  1.0
1   2013-01-03  0   25  2552    899.00  1.0
2   2013-01-05  0   25  2552    899.00  -1.0
3   2013-01-06  0   25  2554    1709.05 1.0
4   2013-01-15  0   25  2555    1099.00 1.0
...
```

Comment: ¿No es un `ts.unstack()`?

Comment: @abulafia si tiennes razón ! Acabo de obtenerlo